# Distinct causes queries to no longer work as expected. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, hierarchical-data, sqlxml

I have a hierarchical table of nodes with 2 tables 'Attributes' and 'Values' linked by a coupling table. Now i'm trying to make a query to return a specific tree with for each node the attributes and values of its child-nodes no matter the level.

Since I did not find a way to do it in one query, I split it into 2 where I get the children separately and recursively using stored procedures. The below query is the one which collects the childnodes and all their info for a specific parent.

However i've come accross some strange behaviour:

I first get the nodes and use a sub-query to get the attributes. Seperately these queries work fine however once I combine them they ignore the filtering and just print all the attributes as soon as I try to eliminate the duplicates using DISTINCT.

```
select xmlelement("tns:nodes",
    xmlattributes('http://somenamespace.com/' as "xmlns:tns"),
    xmlagg(xmlelement("tns:node",
        xmlelement("tns:code", n.code),
        (select xmlelement("tns:attributes",
                xmlagg(xmlelement("tns:attribute",
                    xmlelement("tns:name", t.name)
                ))
            )
            from (select DISTINCT att_a.name
                    from attributes2 att_a
                    inner join attrib_value_node2 att_avnu on att_avnu.attribute_id = att_a.id
                    where att_avnu.node_id in (select id from nodes2 start with code = n.code connect by prior ID = PARENTID)
                 ) t
        )
    )
))
FROM   NODES2 n
where n.parentID in (select id from nodes2 where code = 'TESTS')
and n.id in (select parentID from nodes2)
order by n.code asc;
```

The query works as expected when I remove the DISTINCT. However it has duplicates because there are nodes which have the same attribute but different values. I tried to filter these by only selecting the DISTINCT attributes however for some reason the whole filtering just stops working once I put it there and it just prints all the attributes.

When I run the attribute query separately by manually replacing the n.code with a string it works fine again. Why does the DISTINCT cause problems when the query is run as a whole? Also how can I fix this? I know DISTINCT and collect by are not too friendly to eachother but I did not use them in the same query.

DB script & data:

```
DROP TABLE NODES2;
DROP TABLE VALUES2;
DROP TABLE ATTRIBUTES2;
DROP TABLE ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2;

CREATE TABLE NODES2 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "PARENTID" NUMBER,
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "NODES2_PK" ON "NODES2" ("ID");

CREATE TABLE VALUES2 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "VALUES2_PK" ON "VALUES2" ("ID");

CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTES2 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ATTRIBUTES2_PK" ON "ATTRIBUTES2" ("ID");

CREATE TABLE "ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2" 
(
    "ATTRIBUTE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    "ATTRIB_VALUE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    "NODE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, CODE) VALUES (1,'TESTS');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (2,1,'TST1');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (3,1,'TST2');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (4,1,'TST3');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (5,2,'TST1-1');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (6,2,'TST1-2');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (7,3,'TST2-1');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (8,3,'TST2-2');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (9,3,'TST2-3');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (10,4,'TST3-1');
INSERT INTO "NODES2" (ID, PARENTID, CODE) VALUES (11,4,'TST3-2');

Insert into ATTRIBUTES2 (ID,NAME) values (1,'TestAttribute');
Insert into ATTRIBUTES2 (ID,NAME) values (2,'TestAttribute2');
Insert into ATTRIBUTES2 (ID,NAME) values (3,'TestAttribute3');
Insert into ATTRIBUTES2 (ID,NAME) values (4,'TestAttribute4');
Insert into ATTRIBUTES2 (ID,NAME) values (5,'TestAttribute5');

Insert into "VALUES2" (ID,NAME) values (1,'TestValue1');
Insert into "VALUES2" (ID,NAME) values (2,'TestValue2');
Insert into "VALUES2" (ID,NAME) values (3,'TestValue3');
Insert into "VALUES2" (ID,NAME) values (4,'TestValue4');
Insert into "VALUES2" (ID,NAME) values (5,'TestValue5');

Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (1,1,5);
Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (2,2,5);
Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (1,2,6);
Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (1,3,7);
Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (3,3,8);
Insert into ATTRIB_VALUE_NODE2 (ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIB_VALUE_ID,NODE_ID) values (3,4,8);
```

Output without DISTINCT:

```
<tns:nodes xmlns:tns="http://somenamespace.com/">
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST1</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute2</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST2</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST3</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes/>
    </tns:node>
</tns:nodes>
```

Output with DISTINCT:

```
<tns:nodes xmlns:tns="http://somenamespace.com/">
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST1</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute2</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST2</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute2</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST3</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute2</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
</tns:nodes>
```

expected output:

```
<tns:nodes xmlns:tns="http://somenamespace.com/">
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST1</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute2</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST2</tns:code>
        <tns:attributes>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
            <tns:attribute>
                <tns:name>TestAttribute3</tns:name>
            </tns:attribute>
        </tns:attributes>
    </tns:node>
    <tns:node>
        <tns:code>TST3</tns:code>
    </tns:node>
</tns:nodes>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include some sample data, the result you currently get (with and without distinct), and the result you actually want for that data. All as formatted text rather than images.

Comment: @AlexPoole , I've added the outputs. As you can see the output WITH distinct for some reason stops the filtering from working.

Comment: What is the raw data for those outputs though?

Comment: @AlexPoole I've added an SQL script for you to test with. Tables and data included. I did not add keys or anything. Just the data. I also updated the results and query to fit the tables. I hope you can tell me why this is happening and/or another way how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution plans for your two queries are interesting. I can't immediately see why it's losing the filter steps, or the correlation. You might need to raise an SR to get a full explanation.

You could do it in a single query though, joining a single connect-by to the couling and attribute tables:

```
select xmlserialize(document
  xmlelement("tns:nodes",
    xmlattributes('https//somenamespace.com/' as "xmlns:tns"),
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("tns:node",
        xmlelement("tns:code", t.code),
        xmlelement("tns:attributes",
          xmlagg(
            xmlelement("tns:attribute",
              xmlelement("tns:name", t.name)
            )
            order by t.name
          )
        )
      )
      order by t.code
    )
  )
  indent size = 2
)
from (
  select distinct n.code, a.name
  from (
    select id, prior code as code
    from nodes2
    where id != connect_by_root (id)
    start with code = 'TESTS'
    connect by prior id = parentid
  ) n
  join attrib_value_node2 avn on avn.node_id = n.id
  join attributes2 a on a.id = avn.attribute_id
) t
group by t.code;
```

which with your sample data produces:

```
<tns:nodes xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
  <tns:node xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
    <tns:code xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TST1</tns:code>
    <tns:attributes xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
      <tns:attribute xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
        <tns:name xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TestAttribute</tns:name>
      </tns:attribute>
      <tns:attribute xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
        <tns:name xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TestAttribute2</tns:name>
      </tns:attribute>
    </tns:attributes>
  </tns:node>
  <tns:node xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
    <tns:code xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TST2</tns:code>
    <tns:attributes xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
      <tns:attribute xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
        <tns:name xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TestAttribute</tns:name>
      </tns:attribute>
      <tns:attribute xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">
        <tns:name xmlns:tns="https//somenamespace.com/">TestAttribute3</tns:name>
      </tns:attribute>
    </tns:attributes>
  </tns:node>
</tns:nodes>
```

The XMLSerialize call is only there to format the document nicely.

The namespace declarations are repeated, which seems to be an artefact of nested XMLAgg calls and the associated group-by clause; I can't see a way to not produce those unfortunately, but I suppose technically they are not important.

Comment: Hey @AlexPoole, Thanks for the help. I've analysed the query and while the output does indeed return the response I expect. The logic behind it doesn't seem quite what I required. I should have specified better. If I understand correctly, the query returns the attributes for its direct children. However there can be more levels. In this case I need a list of attributes used by any children no matter what level they are on. So on the highest level in the tree you would have all the attributes and as you go lower in the tree you get less and less. Any idea on how I can do this?